# ds.Tables.Rows.Add() Makes 3 Rows When Called Once

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

[Note Update:]

My desire is for a user adding a new row to a datagridview (DGV) will be able to have that row created in an Access database, and to be able to create multiple rows and non-synchronous edits to those new rows.  The DGV is being filled by a data set table, and I have found having the data set between the DGV and the database is the best practice (or at least allows for flexibility).

To make edits to multiple user created new rows, the data set needs to be able to retrieve the auto-increment primary key from the database, and then refill the DGV with the updated key values for the new rows.  Or at least that is the only way I have found to have this work.  The issue is that when I try to add a row to the datatable, it ends up making three rows instead of one.

---

[Old post deleted for brevity]

Here is how the DGV is first being filled and bound to the data set:

```
Dim ConMain As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & MasterPath)
Dim ds As New DataSet

Public Sub UniversalFiller(ByVal QueryStringFill As String, ByVal DGV As DataGridView, ByVal AccessDBTableName As String)
    If IsNothing(ds.Tables(AccessDBTableName)) Then
    Else
        ds.Tables(AccessDBTableName).Clear()
    End If
    ConMain.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & MasterPath
    Dim daZZ As New OleDbDataAdapter(QueryStringFill, ConMain)
    Try
        daZZ.Fill(ds, AccessDBTableName)
        DGV.DataSource = ds
        DGV.DataMember = AccessDBTableName
        DGV.AutoResizeColumns()
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.GetHashCode, ex.Source, ex.ToString)
        ds.Clear
        MsgBox("There was an error filling the DGV, ds.cleared") 'this is for my notes, not user error'
    End Try

End Sub
```

---

### Update:

I still can't figure out this problem.  This is called when the handling `DGV.UserAddedRow`.  [I've learned that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the original code might not have been the best way to just Add 1 row, but even making a New Row runs into the same problem:

```
Dim daZZ As New OleDbDataAdapter(DBSelectQuery, ConMain)
Dim CurrentCellPoint As Point = DGV.CurrentCellAddress
Dim CurrentCellText As String = DGV.CurrentCell.Value.ToString
Dim cmdBldr As New OleDbCommandBuilder(daZZ)
cmdBldr.QuotePrefix = "["
cmdBldr.QuoteSuffix = "]"
MsgBox("1")
Dim DaZZDataRow As DataRow = ds.Tables(DTName).NewRow
MsgBox("2")
DaZZDataRow(CurrentCellPoint.X) = CurrentCellText
MsgBox("3")
ds.Tables(DTName).Rows.Add(DaZZDataRow)
MsgBox("4")
daZZ.InsertCommand = cmdBldr.GetInsertCommand()
MsgBox("5")
daZZ.Update(ds.Tables(DTName))
MsgBox("6")
ds.Tables(DTName).Clear()
daZZ.Fill(ds, DTName)
MsgBox("5")
daZZ.Update(ds.Tables(DTName))
DGV.CurrentCell = DGV(CurrentCellPoint.X, CurrentCellPoint.Y)
```

The problem is always the `ds.Tables(DTName).Rows.Add()` step.  It doesn't matter what is put in the parentheses on `.Add()`.  It can be anumber or any intiger including 0 and it will make 3 rows.  It doesn't get called multiple times.  Just calling the `ds.Tables(DTName).Rows.Add()`.

If that's not the right way to add one blank row, what is?  I could post the SQL insert/update command, but that's not the problem because the add is making three rows, not 1.  To be clear it will only run through the `MsgBox` items once and yield 3 rows.

Also curious to me, the InsertAt command yields the same result:

`ds.Tables(DTName).Rows.InsertAt(DaZZDataRow, CurrentCellPoint.Y)`
instead of `ds.Tables(DTName).Rows.Add()` still yields 3 new rows.  I've also tried this on a new scratch DB from Access and get the same problem.

[Here is a working example of the code](http://atlled.com/sideprojects/Programming/19938472/TroubleShooting/DummyExcelAddin.7z), as an VS2012 Project plus dummy database.  It's pretty bare-bones, ie no error handling, but it shows the error and also allows deleting rows as an added convenience.  Thanks to anyone who takes a look.

Comment: Mmm are you sure there aren't 3 button clicks? Triggers on the table?

Comment: @Yosi Yep, this triggers when you try to write in a new row cell.

Comment: I think what Yosi is asking here is whether the function getting called three times for some reason? You can confirm this easily by throwing in a Msgbox("This function just got called") into the code and seeing what happens when you click the button once. If it is, that means there's something wrong with the interface; if it's not, then it's something gone wonky with the data updating code. Your first step is to narrow down where the unexpected behavior is coming from.

Comment: @nucleon Thanks for the suggestion, and I tried that.  It is only popping up with one message box.  I remain seriously puzzled by this.  My work around is to immediately delete two of the rows, but that's crude.

Comment: @nucleon  I just posted the updated code, I think based on what you and Yosi were suggesting.  It is in fact not getting called 3 times.  Any other thoughts or trouble shooting?

Comment: @Yosi I didn't add any triggers to the table, the database is an Access database, so could it have gotten triggers automatically from there?

Comment: can you put somewhere a zip file with a working example, code and access db?

Comment: @Fredou would a VS2012 Solution+access db work for you?  I'll make a quick dummy version

Comment: @Fredou Just added a sample project; see the link at the bottom of the question.  Sorry about the delay, I finished it soon after your request, but then got pulled away from the computer for the rest of my shift.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't open your project as I am still on VS2010. However, apart from the "adding rows in triplicate" issue, is the other objective that when you add a new row to the DataGridView it gets updated with the AutoNumber ID of the newly-inserted record? (If so then I may be able to help you with that.)

Comment: @GordThompson That is my actual end goal, and the "adding rows in triplicate" is the error I ran into along the way.  If I'm tackling that wrong altogether I'd love to be put on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a back-to-basics approach to this question, concentrating more on the issue of having the DataGridView show the generated AutoNumber ID value when I add a new record. I started by adding a DataGridView control to my form and using the "Add Project Data Source..." wizard to connect it to the table named [Chemicals] in my Access database "Database1.accdb". (An earlier version of the sample code in the question referred to a table named [Chemicals], so that's what I used.)

When I was finished I had the following "stuff" in my project:

- a DataGridView control (`dataGridView1`) on my form, which was bound to a BindingSource (see below)
- a DataSet (`database1DataSet`) associated with my Access database
- a BindingSource (`chemicalsBindingSource`), associated with the [Chemicals] table in `database1DataSet`, to serve as the `DataSource` for my DataGridView
- a TableAdapter (`chemicalsTableAdapter`) to manage the data flow between the DataSet and the actual database.

The wizard also gave me the following line of code in my `Form1_Load` method. (I used C#, but VB.NET would be very similar.)

```csharp
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.Chemicals' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
this.chemicalsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Chemicals);
```

That was all I needed to run my application and see existing records in my DataGridView.

Now, to push DataGridView updates back to the database and retrieve the AutoNumber value for a newly-created record I used the `RowLeave` event. I found that the `UserAddedRow` event fired too soon (immediately after the user started typing in the new row), and I wanted to wait until the user had finished editing the row before doing anything with it.

The code I wound up using was as follows (again, C#)

```csharp
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fillErUp();
}

private void fillErUp()
{
    // (moved from Form1_Load to its own method so it could also be called from _RowLeave, below)
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.Chemicals' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.chemicalsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Chemicals);
}

private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (dgv.IsCurrentRowDirty)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        dgv.EndEdit();  // flush changes from DataGridView to BindingSource
        chemicalsBindingSource.EndEdit();  // flush changes from BindingSource to DataSet
        this.chemicalsTableAdapter.Update(this.database1DataSet);  // update database
        int currentRow = e.RowIndex;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value) < 0)
        {
            // negative AutoNumber value indicates that the row has just been added
            int currentCol = e.ColumnIndex;
            fillErUp();  // re-fill the table in the DataSet, and hence the DataGridView as well
            dgv.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[currentCol, currentRow];
        }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

This certainly isn't complete production code but I hope it helps.

### Edit re: comments

I took another stab at my previous solution to see if I could accomplish the same results without relying on any Visual Studio "wizardry". My approach this time was:

- I opened a new C# Windows Forms project.
- I dragged-and-dropped a `DataSet` object, a `BindingSource` object, and a `DataGridView` object onto the blank form. They were named `dataSet1`, `bindingSource1`, and `dataGridView1`, respectively.
- I created `Form1_Load` and `dataGridView1_RowLeave` event handlers, and then added my own code that wound up looking like this:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dgvTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        OleDbCommandBuilder cb;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb";
            con.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Chemicals", con);
            cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
            cb.QuotePrefix = "["; cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";
            this.dataSet1.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Chemicals"));
            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.dataSet1;
            this.bindingSource1.DataMember = "Chemicals";
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
            fillErUp();
        }

        private void fillErUp()
        {
            this.dataSet1.Tables["Chemicals"].Clear();
            da.Fill(this.dataSet1.Tables["Chemicals"]);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            if (dgv.IsCurrentRowDirty)
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                dgv.EndEdit();  // flush changes from DataGridView to BindingSource
                bindingSource1.EndEdit();  // flush changes from BindingSource to DataSet
                da.Update(this.dataSet1.Tables["Chemicals"]);  // update database
                int currentRow = e.RowIndex;
                if (dgv.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    // a null ID value indicates that the row has just been added
                    int currentCol = e.ColumnIndex;
                    fillErUp();  // re-fill the table in the DataSet, and hence the DataGridView as well
                    dgv.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[currentCol, currentRow];
                }
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to have play around with this for a bit to see if I can get it to work.  In my actual solution, I have both multiple databases and a dynamic number of tables.  I was hoping to not have to rely on the wizard because of this, but if I can solve the problem "correctly" for one instance, hopefully it will be easier to expand

Comment: @AtlLED I can post a link to a copy of the C# project if you might find it helpful, e.g., to see what "wiring up" the wizard has done in the background.

Comment: That would be helpful, thanks.  I've actually got my original code almost working by turning off and on `DGV.AllowUserToAddRows`, but I'm not able to grab the initial character typed into a new row cell because the value reads as DBNull.  It's only the first character, so I'm trying to grab it now.

Comment: @AtlLED I have updated my answer. You can download a copy of the new "wizard-free" C# project [here](http://wikisend.com/download/190014/dgvTest2.zip).

Comment: Wow that is a wonderful answer.  Give me a day to actually go through it and implement it, but I have a strong feeling this will be the accepted answer.  Just so I understand, you would keep the connection open the entire time the form is open?

Comment: @AtlLED For a connection to an Access database I don't believe that keeping the connection open hurts too much. (Unlike a multi-user client/server database environment where active connections are a more precious commodity.) If you will have multiple concurrent users then adding `Close()` and `Open()` statements will have the effect of flushing the changes out to the other users. (That will happen automatically, but sometimes it takes several seconds for a change on one connection to be visible on other connections.)

Comment: Sorry to come back to this, but how can you properly bind a particular DGV to a particular bs.DataMember? I tried `this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.bindingSource1.Current()` on the idea that just set the datamember, but that doesn't work.  I think this is my last hurtle on this.

Comment: @AtlLED All I did was `this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.bindingSource1` - does that not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is my ***Revised*** take on some parts of your transaction.

```
    daZZ.InsertCommand = cmdBldr.GetInsertCommand()
```

I Still don't think InsertCommand is required. I think this is creating one of your 3 rows.

```
    ds.Tables(DTName).Rows.Add(DaZZDataRow)
```

This is creating your second row. Which is valid, but not needed either.

The THIRD row is being created by the DataGridView due to DataBinding. When you Bind the Table to the DataGridView and the DGV is allowed to "AddRows" it is generating the Inserted Row as well.

Try removing these 2 items totally, as well as the Clear line (I don't think is needed) and I bet you get one row added that is the row presently being added in the DGV.

You will still have to call UPDATE and FILL to resync the data up in the grid.

Comment: Actually I think I do need that to write back to the database.  If I just update the data table, it won't generate the ID's from the Database.  I clear it and then refill it with the primary key from the DB to not run into concurrency problems.  However, even if we ignore the DB all together, and comment out these sections, the `ds.tables(DTname).Rows.Add() line makes 3 rows in the DGV (by itself).  I think that is the real problem.

Comment: Revised Answer. I think this is your issue now.

Comment: I don't think so, I will post the revised code as I understand in the question after I go to a seminar.  From the example, commenting out lines 86-88, 94, 98, and 102 as well as disallowing DGV add-row brings us down to 2 rows being created, but also the table to be doubled and the ID's not fetched which causes concurrency errors.  I will play with this idea some more and update.

Comment: Actually, I think that turning off DGV being able to add rows while leaving everything else in place might be the solution.

Comment: Hopefully it helps you, I normally avoid databinding like the plague because it's a massive black box that can be hard to deal with.

Comment: I want to say that if I had the rep to spare, I would also try and get you a bounty.  The 3 rows were in fact being caused by the DGV being able to create new rows.  Turning that off in the original script made it work, though you loose the first character typed in the row (which I couldn't capture).  That said, the rest of the script seemed to be needed for it to function properly.

Comment: Glad you resolved it. don't worry about it. the number doesn't matter. I think allot of us use this site for the same thing, another place to bounce idea's off when were stuck on something.