# Recall Which DataAdapter from DataTable or DataSet

Tags: .net, datagridview, dataset, dataadapter

I have a solution with multiple datagridviews (DGV), and now multiple bindingsources(BSs) and OleDbDataAdapters (ODA).

This stems from the fact that I have multiple DGV in a tab control, and I want to show different tables from a database in each DGV, as well as be able to CRUD back from the DGV.

Using one BS and ODA, I was able to show all the correct tables in the correct DGV by switching `BS.DataMember` when I entered each tab.  This worked because I only had one DGV per tab.

Where I ran into problems was going back into the database.  I've found that most examples I've found involve using a BS and ODA for each table.  This seems inelegant, so if there was a way to bind the `DataSource` of a DGV to a particular `BS.Datamember` I would love to know it.

Having acquiesced to multiple BS and ODA, I can pull the DGV, table name, and BS needed to update any dirty rows on any of the DGV from one Sub.  What I haven't figured out is if there is a way to get the ODA that was used to fill the table originally.  In Code:

```
Private Sub UniversalDGV_Handler_LeaveRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
         Handles DGV1.RowLeave, DGV2.RowLeave, '...' DGVn.RowLeave 

    Dim DGV As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim bsPass As BindingSource = DGV.DataSource
    Dim CurrentDBTableName As String = bsPass.DataMember
    Dim da as OleDbDataAdapter = 'something I haven't figured out yet
    UniversalDGV_RowLeave(sender, CurrentDBTableName, e, bsPass, da)

End Sub
```

Now in reality, the largest number of DGV I have is 7, so I've just made a matched list and pulled the ODA out that way.  But again that seems very crude.

**Is there a way to retrieve which `DataAdapter` was used from the table it filled, `DataSet` it was used on, [the BS, or DGV]?**

Info from the BS or DGV seems kind of far fetched because of they don't have direct interaction with the ODA from my understanding.  I was also thinking of possibly storing the information in a dataset as I used the adapters, which would at least be a more elegant list/table.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by carefully going through [properties of the DataTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

By using `DataTable.ExtendedProperties()` you can store the DataAdapter used when filling the table.  Code sample:

```
  Dim ds as DataSet
  Dim BS1 as New BindingSource
  Dim da1, da2, da3 as New OleDbDataAdapter
  Private Sub DoSomething(da as OleDbDataAdapter)
        ds.Tables.Add(New DataTable(DBTableName))
        ds.Tables(DBTableName).ExtendedProperties("DataAdapter", da)

  End Sub
  Private Sub DoesSomethingElse() handles DGV1.Rowleave, DGV2.RowLeave, '...' DGVn.RowLeave
    Dim DGV As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim bsPass As BindingSource = DGV.DataSource
    Dim CurrentDBTableName As String = bsPass.DataMember
    Dim RecalledDA as OleDbDataAdapter = ds.Tables(CurrentDBTableName).ExtendedProperties("DataAdapter")
        'Do something with it.  In my case I have a seperate sub I run it all into'
    UniversalDGV_RowLeave(sender, CurrentDBTableName, e, da)
  End Sub
```

Since I have no formal training maybe everyone else knew that, but I hope I can save someone all the hours to figure that out.

With this you can use one BS for all your DGV, assuming you are only showing one at a time.  I think you would still need one BS per DGV if you were showing multiple DGV that required BS.

Comment: @GordThompson Sorry to not have let you know last night, but I figured out how to solve it generally here.  [Your example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369617/ds-tables-rows-add-makes-3-rows-when-called-once?answertab=active#tab-top) worked great with one DGV, this was just my work to expand it to several.